# Getting PHP templates for download

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I have been looking for website templates to download so far I got only one bootstrap template. I can't seem to find much with source code attached with them for download.  Which site do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to find many templates online that have ready made "server-side" code included.  The point of a template is to kick-start the user interface and experience development. Normally it will only include HTML/CSS (and Javascript/Jquery) functionality.  It is up to you (the coder) to fill in the implementation details according to your requirements and language of choice, .NET, PHP etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other bootstrap starter templates http://startbootstrap.com/all-templates